# Display Multiple Images in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to display multiple images in a gridview within a `single` row at a time.

Also I want to make sure that for multiple images uploaded at a time there should be only one row gets inserted into the table.

See my BindGrid() code;-

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id, gallery_id, image_title, image_description, image_path from tbl_gallery_stack order by Id desc");
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    grdGalleryData.DataSource = dt;
                    grdGalleryData.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also see the HTML for gridview:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdGalleryData"
            runat="server"
            Width="100%" border="1"
            Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
            CellPadding="3"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True"
            PageSize="10"
            OnPageIndexChanging="grdGalleryData_PageIndexChanging"
            CssClass="hoverTable"
            DataKeyNames="Id">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="gallery_id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="image_title" HeaderText="Gallery title" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="image_description" HeaderText="Gallery Description" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgDisplay" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Getimage(Eval("image_path").ToString()) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to you visit web site : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0565b55e-3daf-4eef-85ac-a8ab72af4e68/displaying-the-images-into-the-gridview  / regularly !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are querying the data as row-per-image instead of row-with -related-images. So you need to change the database query pattern to something like below (**Its just for demonstration purpose to hold nested dataset**):

```
       void BindGrid()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter personAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PersonTable", con))
                using (SqlDataAdapter personImagesAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PersonImages", con))
                {

                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("PersonAndImagesDataSet");
                    personAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "PersonTable");
                    personImagesAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "PersonImages");

                    DataRelation personWithImages = dataSet.Relations.Add("PersonAndImages", dataSet.Tables["PersonTable"].Columns["Id"],
     dataSet.Tables["PersonImages"].Columns["Person_Id"]);
                    if (grdGalleryData.DataSource == null)
                    {
                        grdGalleryData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["PersonTable"];
                        grdGalleryData.DataBind();
                    }


                }
            }
        }
```

In the HTML you can include a ListView (or a control of your choice to hold list items) and on GridView's databind event do something like this:

**ASPX View**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdGalleryData"
        runat="server"
        Width="100%" border="1"
        Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
        CellPadding="3"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="3"
        CssClass="hoverTable"
        DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="grdGalleryData_RowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Gallery title" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvImages" OnDataBinding="lvImages_DataBinding" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="imgDisplay" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' Width="50px" Height="50px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Databinding to ListView (C#)**

```
protected void grdGalleryData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                var personId = Convert.ToInt32((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["Id"]);
                var imageListView = e.Row.FindControl("lvImages") as ListView;

                //Just for demo purpose. Get only required image data based on the parent table id  in actual code.
                if (data == null)
                {
                    data = GetData();
                }
                //In below line, based on the parent table id , get the image data from data store. Just for brevity I am querying a complete dataset on every row data bind.
               //E.g: var resultRows =  DataStore.GetImage(int personId); and bind this to ListView directly.
                var resultRows = data.Tables["PersonImages"].AsEnumerable().Where(img => img.Field<int>("Person_Id") == personId); 
                DataTable dtImages = new DataTable();
                if (resultRows != null && resultRows.Count()>0)
                    dtImages = resultRows.CopyToDataTable();

                imageListView.DataSource = dtImages; //Here you should be assigning result table/collection that you get from data store.
                imageListView.DataBind();
            }
 }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @RahulSutar If this solution help you fix your problem, then don't forget to mark it answer!!